# gulp-uglify, не выходить из watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

Есть такой таск для js:
[image: ага]
Для проверки правильности js использую JSHint для Sublime Text 3.
Тем не менее, когда таск `watch` запущен, производится сохранение js (сохранение запускает JSHint для ST3) с ошибками и запускается таск `js`, в котором происходит `uglify()`, таск `watch` вылетает и просто выводится строка для ввода.
Надоело каждый раз заново запускать сервак через дефолтный таск, так что хотелось бы с этим разобраться: как выводить ошибку, но не выходить из таска `watch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для этого "держатель ошибок".
Самый простой способ поставить [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) в самом начале потока каждого таска (после gulp.src). И тогда, если появится ошибка, то watch не падает, а просто выплевывает ошибку.

Comment: О, нормас. Попробую, помечу тогда как ответ, если справится с задачей. Спасибо)